# Would a reset IC be enough for this many power supplies?

Tags: reset, power-sequencing

Could you please let me know how many reset ICs I'd need for my board?

I'm designing a camera using the [IMX225LQR Image Sensor](http://www.ryida.com/upfile/IMX225LQR-C_E_TechnicalDatasheet_Rev0.2.pdf). This sensor requires 3 different input voltages: 1.2v, 1.8v and 3.3v as power source. So I would have 5V source voltage and 3 voltage regulators. For power on/off sequencing a [LM3880](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm3880-q1.pdf) would be used. For power on reset I was considering using a reset IC to monitor the Vout of 3.3v regulator. But I heard that people use reset IC for detecting voltage drop in power supply pins(brownout reset). My question is this, do I need to monitor Vout of the three regulators for the brownout reset?

Comment: Your dropbox link requires registration. Please embed a link to the original document or, better still, embed a photo or screengrab in your question. Why do you need external reset? For most devices we just use an RC reset delay on power-up.

Comment: @transistor I can access the dropbox link without logging in. Either way, [this](http://www.ryida.com/upfile/IMX225LQR-C_E_TechnicalDatasheet_Rev0.2.pdf) appears to be the same document.

Comment: I'm sorry for very poor question. I eddited it as suggested.

Answer (score 1):

If you use regulators with an enable pin, you could achieve your power sequencing with very little effort by using some RC delays. Essentially you would power on DVdd, the output of that would go through an RC delay into the enable of OVdd, and that output would go through an RC delay into the enable for AVdd. All of the regulators voltage inputs would be sourced from a common voltage. Another simple option would be to use some 555 timers and feed the enable pins.

Comment: I eddited my question to make it clear. I think I already have solution for the power on/off sequencing. But I'm not sure how to make brownout reset.

Answer (score 0):

There are two condition that you need a reset

1) Hardware Reset or Power up

2) Software Reset

When you power digital logic up (transistor pairs) they need an adequate voltage before they will function as intended. The reset signal has to be held for more than a one clock cycle to ensure that all of the digital logic (flipflops) have had time to clear and return to a 'reseted' state. If you have several flip flops in a row it can take more time to clear. This is to prevent metastablitiy where the memory comes up in an undetermined state.

On page 101 it shows how long the reset needs to be held low, its 500ns. You also need to be able to do this if you want to reset the sensor via a software reset (and I can't remember, but I think it is also 500ns). The reset chips facilitate the reset. 500ns is also a minimum time, the reset can be held for longer than 500ns, so a 1us reset chip should work.

If you want to generate your power on sequencing signal, there are lots of examples with [FPGA's](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/slyt079/slyt079.pdf) and LDOS or this [search](https://www.google.com/search?sclient=psy-ab&btnG=Search&q=image%20sensor%20power%20up%20voltage%20sequencing) or this [one](https://www.google.com/search?q=fpga%20power%20up%20voltage%20sequencing&spell=1&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiCvf6D3_zKAhUIxmMKHac7CtsQvwUIGigA)